# WAMP HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found PHPadmin

Tags: wamp

Hi I've just downloaded WAMP got everything set up apart from phpadmin. When I click on the phpadmin button it takes to a webpage and has the error sign

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to navigate to phpmyadmin on your localhost?  For example:  http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks for your help that has made it work. But i had to type it it in manually is there anyway for it to come up automatically. Thanks

Comment: When you talk about automatically do you mean when you click on the phpmyadmin button?

Comment: Yeah at the moment I click on the phpAdmin on wamp i get an error. Then when i enter localhost:8888 in url it works.

Comment: You could edit your wamp index page to go to the localhost:8888 but I suspect you need fix your configuration